# Tortoise SVN Diff fails to notice similarities in long lines

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, diff

I was trying to diff 2 copies of an essay using TSVN diff but when I made a second revision (revision 3) and tried to diff it with revision 2, diff simply highlighted everything orange in the left pane and highlighted everything yellow in the right pane as added. I have no idea why it's doin this, as it seemed to work fine for my first and second revision:

In this screenshot, "This summer" Shouldn't be highlighted orange on the left side and it shouldnt be highlighted yellow on the right. It's showing everything as changed, which is not helping.

[image: Broken Diff]

Here is what it looekd like for my other revision when it was working. Notice how only changed things are yellow on the right:

[image: Working Diff]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TortoiseMerge only shows inline diffs for a line if the changes are small. If there are too many changes in one line, it treats that line as completely different and does not show inline diff.

If you want to override this behavior (for which there is no option in the Settings), you can use the Registry Editor to Create a DWORD registry entry HKCU\Software\TortoiseMerge\InlineDiffMaxLineLength. Default is 3000 chars. You can set a higher value if your lines are longer, but be aware that this has an effect on performance.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a way to force it? That second pic is a 3 paragraph essay, each paragraph as 1 line, diffed between versions. For some reason it worked fine for that one... I searched through the options and found no way to force it to still diff single lines that are dissimilar.

Comment: Create a DWORD registry entry HKCU\Software\TortoiseMerge\InlineDiffMaxLineLength. Default is 3000 chars. You can set a higher value if your lines are longer, but be aware that this has an effect on performance.